# service mongod cant start, permission denied mongod.lock when changing dbpath

Tags: mongodb, permissions, mongodb-3.4

What i want to do: change dbpath of mongodb from /var/lib/mongodb to /home/user/mongodb/data

im using db version v3.4.7

what i've done

```
mkdir -p ~/mongodb/data
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb  /home/user/mongodb
```

change /etc/mongodb.conf

```
storage:
  dbPath: /home/user/mongodb/data/
  journal:

sudo mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf
```

this works. Also tried

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /home/user/mongodb/data/
```

command works fine

```
sudo service mongod start
```

command fails. checking the log file.

> Permission denied: "/home/user/mongodb/data/mongod.lock", terminating

what is going on? I've tried everything i know. even tried setting chmod 777 to the lock file, and still has permission denied.

Comment: Please see this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300861/mongodb-only-works-when-run-as-root-on-ubuntu-data-directory-issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you now command:

```
sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb  /home/user/mongodb
sudo service mongod restart
```

It will work!

Problems here was that you gave command `sudo mongod --dbpath /home/user/mongodb/data/` what created ROOT ownded files to that `/home/user/mongodb/data/` directory and your "normal" mongodb user don't have right to overwrite those.

So, NEVER start your mongod as root OR if you do so, remember reset ownership of those data files back to mongodb.

Comment: I tried that!  but apparently not all of the files were not owned by mongod.  eventually my fix was going into /home/user/mongodb, cd /home/user/mongodb/data and doing sudo chmod mongodb:mongodb *,
also did sudo chmod -R 775 /home/user/mongodb, not sure if needed make sure /home/user has permissions chmod 755

Answer (score 0):

I execute "sudo mongod --dbpath /path/to/mongo" on Centos 7 with Mongo 4 and that's ok but to repair or work as here recommended, you must remove and install.

When you remove you make sure that the execute the correct command to start over:

- sudo yum remove mongodb-org* (to delete all configuration)

Then reinstall and continue:

- sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
- sudo systemctl stop mongod
- mv /var/lib/mongo /{path}/mongo
- sudo vi /etc/mongod.conf (inline dbPath change the path to "/{path}/mongo")
- chown mongod:mongod -R /{path}/mongo/
- sudo systemctl start mongod

Answer (score 0):

**Change path in mongodb in redhat 8**

Eg: Your new location should be inside /new_drive

create new directory inside /new_drive

```
cd  /new_drive 
sudo mkdir database
```

make user as mongod in new path

```
sudo chown -R mongod:mongod database
```

Update SELinux policy (This is important) [details here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/)

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t mongod_var_lib_t ./database.*
sudo chcon -Rv -u system_u -t mongod_var_lib_t  /database
restorecon -R -v /database
```

if there is any problem add these command:

```
/sbin/restorecon -v /database/*
sudo ausearch -c 'mongod' --raw | audit2allow -M my-mongod
sudo semodule -X 300 -i my-mongod.pp
```

Restart mongo

```
sudo systemctl restart mongod
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case when using mongodb-community in MacOS.

```
$ sudo chown -R root:admin /usr/local/var/mongodb
```