# permission denied on mongod.lock, despite it being owned by mongodb

Tags: mongodb, linux

this is my mongod.lock:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb mongodb    0 Dec  3 17:09 mongod.lock
```

hence this solution doesn't apply: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/183018

this is how I start mongodb:

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```

and this is the output in mongod.log:

```
2019-12-03T17:12:01.676+0100 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: Location28596: Unable to determine status of lock file in the data directory /run/media/minze/ssd/mongodb: boost::filesystem::status: Permission denied: "/run/media/minze/ssd/mongodb/mongod.lock", terminating
```

thanks in advance. I really don't see how mongodb would not be permitted to access a file owned by mongodb

Comment: it works when the path is not /run/media/minze/ssd/mongodb/ but /var/lib/mongodb. Even when the directory in /run is copied by using cp -a so that all permissions remain the same. Why is that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works after I did:

```
sudo chmod +r /run/media/minze/ssd
sudo chmod +x /run/media/minze/ssd
```

I don't understand why.

mongodb.lock is located in /run/media/minze/ssd/mongodb/mongodb.lock

ls -lha gives me (permissions of '.' are important here):

```
drwxr-xr-x 8 minze   minze   4.0K Dec  3 17:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root      60 Dec  3 10:49 ..
drwx------ 2 root    root     16K Oct 15 20:24 lost+found
drwx------ 4 mongodb mongodb 4.0K Dec  3 17:54 mongodb
```

now

Answer (score 0):

The same situation but I also had to do (database location is /mnt/database1/mongodb):

```
sudo chmod +x ./database1
```

And ls -lha gives me:

```
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root    4,0K мар  4 21:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root    root    4,0K фев 21 06:29 ..
drwxr-xr-x  5 root    root      70 фев 10 18:44 archive
drwx------  3 user    user      25 мар  4 21:44 database
drwxr-xr-x  3 user    user      21 мар  4 21:49 database1
```

The same database in the folder ./database doesn't work. And what is most interesting it had worked until I reboot the system one day. The "permission denied" error had appeared suddenly without any seemed reasons.